# Is it possible to send data invisible for Wireshark/libpcap?

Tags: network-programming

I'm just playing around and wonder if it is possible, to send data from my Computer that is invisible for Wireshark?
I've never done any network programming lower than using libpcap/WinPcap, so I would be happy for any suggestions...

Comment: no, just think about it..

Comment: That's like speaking to a person who can hear you, but in such a way that they can't hear you.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a network protocol analyzer for Unix and Windows.
So if you want something to send through a network but can't be examine by wireshark what you can do is to implement your own protocol. But that is an easy task. There is a set of protocols that Wireshark can handle. If you build your own protocol and communicate using that then wireshark can't use to inspect that. (Technically wireshark can be use to capture network traffic but it can't decode since it doesn't know how to decode your protocol)

Answer (score 0):

`pcap` (the **p**acket **cap**ture backend used by Wireshark, among others) can sniff anything at the link layer of the OSI model. This means it can capture anything that goes down the network wire. In a home network this means it's capable of picking up Ethernet frames, and obviously everything above that (IP->TCP->HTTP, for example).

To avoid detection:

- physically disconnect the listening machine, or place it behind a switch.
- use an interface that pcap doesn't support. Maybe serial ports? This likely means you can't use your OS's network stack, as pcap will likely support anything your OS does.
- find a bug inside Wireshark to make it crash or break it in some way. HIGHLY unlikely.
- for commodity hardware and networks you don't control: impossible.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, I don't want to send some data and want it to be invisible at the destination, it should be invisible just on my side.

In detail:
I'm running Wireshark on my computer and send some data from my computer.
If I build the frame completely by myself and find a way to pass it to my network interface without touching any of the "usual parts" it could be invisible on my computer. As soon as it is on the wire it will be detected by any system connected.

Comment: You didn't make that clear in your question. You should edit the question with clarifications, because comments get buried.

Comment: So you want to go for my 2nd bullet point. Use something pcap doesn't support. So custom, incompatible drivers.